# How to delete record from database with checkbox in telerik radgridview C#

Tags: c#, database, checkbox, radgridview

I want to delete record from database with checkbox in telerik radgridview
...
Please Help Me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the code below.  That should do what you want!!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Import Data";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Column1});
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 43);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(692, 209);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
            //this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellContentClick);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(144, 13);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "Export Data";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(331, 13);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button3.Text = "Delete If CheckBox Checked";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(717, 264);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Column1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    }
}
```